# How to specify zookeeper clientPortAddress with HBase?

Tags: apache, hbase, apache-zookeeper

Installed Standalone HBase using the [Quick Start Guide](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#quickstart), but I need to bind all ports to a particular interface, so I set various [*bindAddress properties](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#config.files) in conf/hbase-site.xml and ran `bin/start-hbase.sh`, but the zookeeper clientPort is still bound to `:::2181`:

```
# netstat -antop | grep LISTEN | grep 4232/java
tcp6 0 0 :::2181              :::*    LISTEN  4232/java
tcp6 0 0 10.134.6.221:41474   :::*    LISTEN  4232/java
tcp6 0 0 10.134.6.221:16010   :::*    LISTEN  4232/java
tcp6 0 0 127.0.0.1:34212      :::*    LISTEN  4232/java
tcp6 0 0 127.0.0.1:34636      :::*    LISTEN  4232/java
```

The bundled version of zookeeper appears to be 3.4.6

```
# ls lib/zookeeper-*
lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar
```

This should have the [`clientPortAddress` option](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_configuration):

```
 clientPortAddress
  New in 3.3.0: the address (ipv4, ipv6 or hostname) to listen for client connections; that is, the address that clients attempt to connect to. This is optional, by default we bind in such a way that any connection to the clientPort for any address/interface/nic on the server will be accepted.
```

But specifying that option like so in `conf/hbase-site.xml` doesn't work:

```
<configuration>
  <property><name>hbase.rootdir</name><value>file:///root/hbase</value></property>
  <property><name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name><value>/root/zookeeper</value></property>
  <property><name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPortAddress</name><value>10.134.6.221</value></property>
  <property><name>hbase.master.info.bindAddress</name><value>10.134.6.221</value></property>
  <property><name>hbase.regionserver.info.bindAddress</name><value>10.134.6.221</value></property>
</configuration>
```

I tried to create a zoo.cfg file with clientPortAddress and put it in various directories and HBASE_CLASSPATH, but HBase didn't seem to pick it up.

Comment: try to disable ipv6 http://ask.xmodulo.com/disable-ipv6-linux.html

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan Thanks but I set `net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1`, rebooted, confirmed that `inet6 addr` is gone from ifconfig, and started hbase, and now it is listening on 0.0.0.0:2181 instead of :::2181, but it's still listening on all interfaces which is not what I want.